# where can i find a list of field names for tfs work items?

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk

```
WorkItemCollection workItemCollection = workItemStore.Query(
                " SELECT [System.Id], [System.WorkItemType]," +
                " [System.State], [System.AssignedTo], [System.Title] " +
                " FROM WorkItems " +
                " WHERE [System.TeamProject] = '" + tfsProject.Name +
                "' ORDER BY [System.WorkItemType], [System.Id]");
```

There is a bug with using select * so I want to know where can I find a list of all the fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TFS provides a command for this (and much more), `witadmin`. It is located in the `Common7/IDE` folder of your Visual Studio installation.

For listing fields, the command syntax should be:

```
witadmin listfields /collection:http://my.tfs.server/MyCollection
```

Answer (score 2):

The full list of the fields can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194971.aspx)

[image]